# How to check location authorization status at the click of a button in iOS 14?

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios14

How can I use Core Location's locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_:) method to check authorization status and report user location at the press of a button (called in @IBAction) below:

My issue here is that when I run the code in the simulator, CoreLocation doesn't pop up with an alert to ask the user for permission when the button is pressed.

```
class CurrentLocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    // Button to check authorization status and start sending location update to the delegate
    @IBAction func getLocation() {
        locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager)
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // Delegate method to check authorization status and request "When In Use" authorization
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        let authStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
        if authStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Using the deprecated authorizationStatus() class method in the @IBAction method instead of the locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_:) method allows me to get the pop up when the button is pressed in the simulator. I'm still trying to figure out why this modification works whereas my code above doesn't.

```
    @IBAction func getLocation() {
        let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if authStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        }
        ...
```

Comment: The same way you do that in `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization`

Comment: @pronebird Could you clarify what you mean by the "same way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code works - but have you remembered to add the privacy usage descriptions to the info.plist file?

Add these two entries in the file with your own explanation in the value field, then it should popup in the simulator:

- Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Comment: Yes, I added the privacy usage descriptions as well, however no luck with it popping up in the simulator. I've noticed that I can get this pop-up when I use the deprecated authorizationStatus() class method instead of the locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization delegate method in my edit above.

Comment: I've copied your code, created a new VC with a button which calls getLocation(), and with the two usage descriptions in my plist file, the simulator ask for location. Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: I was having issues with running XCode 12.2 beta files on my iPhone's iOS 14.1 so I wasn't able to test on a real device. But I was able to downgrade to XCode 12 and the code ended up working on my iPhone. I appreciate your help @perage, thank you!